# MWS fba api bad request c#

Tags: c#, amazon-mws, fba

hi i am testing MarketplaceWebService.Samples.But it responses alway bad request. invaild request.
can anyone help to take a look.
thanks.

```
SubmitFeedRequest request = new SubmitFeedRequest();
            request.Merchant = merchantId;
            request.MWSAuthToken = "<Your MWS Auth Token>"; // Optional
            request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
            request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>(new string[] { marketplaceId });



            request.FeedContent = File.Open("feed.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


            request.ContentMD5 = MarketplaceWebServiceClient.CalculateContentMD5(request.FeedContent);
            request.FeedContent.Position = 0;

            request.FeedType = "_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_";

            SubmitFeedSample.InvokeSubmitFeed(service, request);
```

feed.xml 
    
    
    
    1.01
    machantid
    
    Product
    false
    
    1
    Update
    
    testsku
    
    UPC
    123456789

Comment: It is alway 400 bad request. pls ponit out  what is wrong.